# What is the difference between memberAction and collectionAction in ember-api-actions

Tags: ember.js

I am new the ember , what is the difference between memberAction and collectionAction in ember-api-actions.

i know these are used to get response data from backend . thanks .

Comment: since it is more specific to a package used in Ember, [Discord](https://discord.gg/emberjs) or [Discuss](https://discuss.emberjs.com/) would be a fastest and great place to get help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A member action happens on a specific resource and a collection action happens on the whole collection. For instance, `POST /users/sync` is a collection action and `POST /users/1/promote` is a member action.

You might also find [Ember Custom Actions](https://github.com/Exelord/ember-custom-actions) of use for this kind of thing.